# Tensorflow: Ordered Probit Model application in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I'm trying to use Tensorflow to build an Ordered Probit Machine Learning algorithm. While my actual application is fairly complicated, I rewrote my code to be more general. It is displayed in this post.

I cannot better explain the Ordered Probit any better than wikipedia can: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_probit

The problem with the code, however, is quite straightforward. The function I'm trying to optimize contains a few conditions, and I strongly suspect that it is in one of these statements a

> ValueError: (Shapes (100,) and () are not compatible)

is generated. I read all about shapes on this page of the Tensorflow documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/resources/dims_types.html and I tried to play around with the shapes of the variables, but I can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance for spending time in trying to help me out here. It is much appreciated!

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf


# Tensorflow application for an Ordered Probit Model
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_probit

# Create 100 phony x, y_star data points in NumPy, y_star = x * 0.1 + 0.3
x_data = np.random.rand(100).astype(np.float32)
y_star = x_data * 0.5 + 0.3

# Set true values for mu1 and mu2
mu1 = 0.45
mu2 = 0.60

# Build the 'true' y-data (the observed y values in the ordered probit model)
y_data = np.zeros(100).astype(np.float32)
for i, val in enumerate(y_star):
    if val < mu1:
        y_data[i] = 0.0
    elif val > mu2:
        y_data[i] = 1.0
    else:
        y_data[i] = 0.5

# Initialize all variables that should be estimated
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
mu1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))
mu2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))


# The actual model, it is an Ordered Probit Model
# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_probit
is_less_than_mu1 = tf.less(W * x_data + b, mu1, name="is_less_than_mu1")
is_more_than_mu2 = tf.greater(W * x_data + b, mu2, name="is_more_than_mu2")

pred = tf.cond(is_less_than_mu1,
               lambda: 0.0,
               tf.cond(is_more_than_mu2,
                       lambda: 1.0,
                       lambda: 0.5
                       ))

# Minimize the mean squared errors.
loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(pred - y_data))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)

# Before starting, initialize the variables.  We will 'run' this first.
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

# Launch the graph.
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

# Fit the line.
for step in range(201):
    sess.run(train)
    if step % 20 == 0:
        print(step, sess.run(W), sess.run(b), sess.run(mu1), sess.run(mu2))

# Should learn best fit is W: [0.1], b: [0.3], mu1: [0.45], mu2: [0.60]
```

Comment: I'd guess you need to return the tensor of the same size as the predicates after `lambda`s.

Comment: Hi Sygi, thanks for your reply! Do you have more specific information on how to do this. I cannot seem to get it right.

Comment: My suggestion was to substitute, e.g. `0.` with `tf.constant(0.0, shape=[100])`, but it is a blind guess.

Comment: Hi Sygi, I tried to implement this, but to no avail. Thanks for your reply though! :-)

Comment: @Bas, did you ever get this working?  I am in need of an ordered probit model, and a python implementation would be super convenient.